# Show that $\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}$ doesn't exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Hey everyone I would like to have a hint on this one, please?
$\lim\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}$  doesn't exist

Comment: Perform a substitution $x=1/t$ and consider the limit then for t to infinity and negative infinity. It becomes clear what is going on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $x=\frac{1}{2\pi n}$ you will get the limit is zero (as $n\to\infty$). Taking $x=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n}$ you will get the limit is $\infty$. Conclusion?

Comment: Taking the latter definitely makes the limit approach ∞. However, I see that taking the former makes the limit approach 0 times ∞ so how is that equivalent to zero?

Comment: Alright problem solved by taking x = 1/[-π/2+2πn] and y = 1/[π/2+2πn]

Comment: @OmarQasem It is not really $0\cdot\infty$ in the first case. It is zero times a large but finite number, and it is zero.

Comment: I don't see how is it large but finite. When plugging x=1/2πn in the function we get 2πn * sin(2πn) and as n → ∞ this should go to ∞ times zero

Comment: @OmarQasem $\sin(2\pi n)=0$ exactly for all $n$. It gives that $2\pi n\cdot\sin(2\pi n)=2\pi n\cdot 0=0$ for all $n$. The zero sequence has the limit, and it is zero.

Answer (score 1):

As $x \to 0$,
$\frac1{x} \to \infty$
so
$\sin(\frac1{x})$
oscillates faster and faster.
So this, by itself,
does not have a limit.

As $x \to 0$,
$\frac1{x} \to \infty$
so
$\frac{\sin(\frac1{x})}{x}$
doubly fails to have a limit:
it oscillates faster and faster
at the same time
it grows infinitely large.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ t = \frac{1}{x}$, then we have if $x \to 0^+$

$$ \lim_{ t \to \infty} t \sin t $$

Which we show does not exist. Suppose it does exist, then choosing $\epsilon = 1$, then can find some $N$ large enough so that $ | t \sin t - L | < 1 $ for all $t > N$. Now, notice

$$ L - 1 < t \sin t < L + 1 \; \; \; \; \; \text{all} \; \; t > N $$

but, if we pick $t = \frac{ 3 L \pi }{2}$, then

$$ t\sin t = \frac{ 3 L \pi }{2} > L +1 $$

Comment: How is it that sin t = 1 as t = 3LPi/2 ?

Answer (score 0):

$\lim_{x\to 0}\dfrac{\sin \dfrac{1}{x}}{x}=\lim _{t\to \infty} t\sin t$.

Take $x_n=(2n+1)\dfrac{\pi}{2}$ and $y_n=n\pi$.

Both $x_n,y_n\to \infty$

If $f(x)=t\sin t$.

Then $f(x_n)\to \infty $ as $n\to \infty $and $f(y_n)=0$ as $n\to \infty $

So the limit does not exist